# Internet browsing problems when the Mac is bound to a Microsoft server with Active Directory

Tags: macos, active-directory

I have set up Active Directory on my Mac and I can log in and authenticate fine to the server. When I try to browse the Internet, there is an error which says "The user could not be determined by the Single Sign-on agent". I believe the Internet is filtered through Bluecoat, so I was wondering how to browse the Internet as it's trying to request my Active Directory username but the browser is not picking it up.

I've had a look at the settings in Safari, but I just can't see anything about this.

---

I tried using Authoxy but I still can't browse or go to the app store. I have no problems with Active Directory as I can log in and can see all the other computers and servers.

Comment: This is something you need to ask your IT department about.

Comment: I cannot access the App store either because of this. I'm not sure how to configure the account to be able to access Internet once I log in via Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your proxy server requires [NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM_Authentication) (this is a way in Windows where the logged in Windows session is used to transparently authenticate to the proxy). [Authoxy](http://www.hrsoftworks.net/Products.php) supports this on OS X.